# Oшибка в Keras - variable 'photoshop'

Tags: python, keras

Непонятная ошибка всплывает при работе с листингом из книги:

```
local variable 'photoshop' referenced before assignment
```

При обучении модели с генераторами спустя несколько итераций внутри эпохи появляется такая ошибка. На Стеке есть рекомендация  [сделать даунгрейд Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587941/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-photoshop-referenced-before-assignment), но мне не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решилась не даунгрейдом, а апгрейдом до версии Pillow 6.1.0